# Synchronising scrolling of two surfacelistboxes wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

Is it possible to scroll a surface list box from C# code behind?? Or synchronise the scrolling of two surface listboxes some other way??

Comment: I think I've found the answers here, sorry to waste a topic:

http://www.software-architects.com/TechnicalArticles/ScrollSync/tabid/101/Default.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacescrollviewer.aspx

Comment: I'm going to find this tricky adapting the code explained in the first article to work with the surface sdk - if anyone can be of any help I'd raelly appreciate it.

Comment: That code should work pretty much as-is.  What part is tricky?